# Output XML from combined XML's in a XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I got some huge problems figuring how to output a clean XML from an XSL that imports two XML's and combines the data.

I was trying to find more info about `<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>` which i think is my solution but i don't get how to get all of it into one solid xml file. When i call it from a server-script it looks nice but it has some `HTML` tags and other stuff that i don't want there, i guess it's because it's still a XSL.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="source-producenter" select="'Producers.xml'"/>
  <xsl:param name="source-positioner" select="'positioner.xml'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="producenter" select="document($source-producenter)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="Workbook" select="document($source-positioner)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Producers>
      <xsl:for-each select="$producenter//producer">
        <producer>

          <id>
            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
          </id>

          <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
          </name>

          <address><xsl:value-of select="address"/></address>

          <postalcode>
            <xsl:value-of select="postalcode"/>
          </postalcode>

          <city>
            <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
          </city>

          <site>
            <xsl:value-of select="site"/>
          </site>

          <pic>
            <xsl:value-of select="img"/>
          </pic>
          <!--Store id from producent into storeId xsl variable -->
          <xsl:variable name="storedId" select="id"/>
          <!--Using filter to get correct Cells for latitude and longitude and checks if text() in number is equal to our storedId variable-->
          <xsl:variable name="selected"
            select="$Workbook//ss:Cell[@ss:Index='2']/ss:Data[@ss:Type='Number' and text() = $storedId]"/>
          <!--Gets the filtered values-->
          <latitude>
            <xsl:value-of select="$selected//../../ss:Cell[2]/ss:Data"/>
          </latitude>
          <longitude>
            <xsl:value-of select="$selected//../../ss:Cell[3]/ss:Data"/>
          </longitude>
        </producer>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Producers>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I appriciate all answers, thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide: 1.The exact two XML documents (as small as possible, please). 2. The exact result you are getting when the transformation is applied on these two XML dcouments. 3. What is wrong in the results you are getting. 4. The exact result (for these two specified XML documents) that you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're transforming XML produced by MSExcel (clue is the ss: prefix on some of the elements), then be aware to the way Excel uses the @ss:Index attribute.  Cells that are contiguous omit this attribute, but to skip blank intervening cells the subsequent cell has an @ss:index.  It's fairly painful to reconstruct the geometry of a partly-filled matrix of cells.  I can't quite understand if this has anything to do with your challenge.